# Cross-correlation of two functions which are not fixed

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform

I am trying to cross-correlate two functions, but one of which is changing each 'step' of the cross-correlation.

I want to cross-correlate `T(f)` and `M(g(f))`, where `g(f) = A*B^((f-C)/D)`.

I understand that if the two functions are static, then a cross-correlation would simply be achieved by taking the fourier transform of both, multiplying them together, then inverse fourier transform.

However when one of the functions varies, I was thinking of using something similar to a Mellin transform, but I'm not sure what exactly.

Note: my functions are discrete, but any continuous formalisation should do for now.